# JPA and database interaction

Tags: spring, jpa, jdbc, spring-boot

I am quite new to Spring and JPA environment. I wrote small code that stores information of Offices by using `repository.save(Office object)` operation. But when I rerun the code it shows that there is no such entry (that I entered before). How can I permanently store information in a database using JPA?

Comment: Well, in JPA you persist entities to a database by associating them with a persistence unit.  Maybe you should show us some code of what you've tried so far so that we don't have to rewrite a tutorial on JPA for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only use h2 without any configuration (only dependency in gradle/maven), then spring will create inmemory db for you. To change this setting you can create your own `DataSource` Bean. Also there is a simpler way if you use spring boot - just configure it in `application.properties`.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:<path to to store url>;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: Yes, I am using just h2. But the problem is after saving entry in first run, it shows in second run that there is no such entry. I think every time Spring recreate h2 database, is it true?

Comment: inmemory db which is created by default is not persistent. If you choose file or url to sql server then it will be persistent ;)